# java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a reg expression which has the exact same meaning as the "*" operator in a linux / windows command line. For example, find all files that: starts with 0 or more random chars, contains "abc" in the middle, and ends with 0 or more random chars.

So something like this in Java:

```
if (test.match("*abc*"))
    System.out.println("found match");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original answer:

```
.*abc.*
```

Is the regexp which solves your problem.  Note that if you want to match newline as part of your test string, you might need to enable single-line mode.

Revised answer if you are really talking about files:

```
[^/]*abc[^/]*
```

is a better answer since globs do not actually match directories in "*".  For example, /etc/*bar will match /etc/foobar but will not match /etc/foo/bar.  However, you said you were not interested in filenames, so the difference may be irrelevant to you.

Comment: That was basically what I came up with too, except that I used the brackets like Vivien mentioned; thought I'd ask here to make sure I was doing it right :)

Comment: @user85116: Answer revised to discuss globs not matching directories, though you may not care.

Answer (score 2):

`*` in Unix is expressed as `(.*)` in regular expressions.

```
if (test.match("(.*)abc(.*)")) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: The parentheses are optional. They signify making it a matching group, which may or may not be wanted.

Comment: Adam, can you explain your comment a little more?

Comment: Anything in parens captures the contents, so you can in java find out exactly what the prefix and suffix of abc is.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to '[glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)' more than a full regex.   Check this page out http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html

Comment: Thanks Andrew; I just used the file concept to explain what I wanted out of the *  I'm not actually looking for files  :)